# How to expose Spark Driver behind dockerized Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, apache-zeppelin

I am currently building a custom docker container from a plain distribution with Apache Zeppelin + Spark 2.x inside.

My Spark jobs will run in a remote cluster and I am using `yarn-client` as master.

When I run a notebook and try to print `sc.version`, the program gets stuck. If I go to the remote resource manager, an application has been created and accepted but in the logs I can read:

`INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for Spark driver to be reachable`

My understanding of the situation is that the cluster is unable to talk to the driver in the container but I don't know how to solve this issue.

I am currently using the following configuration:

- `spark.driver.port` set to `PORT1` and option `-p PORT1:PORT1` passed to the container
- `spark.driver.host` set to `172.17.0.2` (ip of the container)
- `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` set to `172.17.0.2` (ip of the container)
- `spark.ui.port` set to `PORT2` and option `-p PORT2:PORT2` passed to the container

I have the feeling I should change the SPARK_LOCAL_IP to the host ip but if I do so, SparkUI is unable to start, blocking the process a step before.

Thanks in advance for any ideas / advices !

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, actually, if I set `spark.driver.host` to be different (the host ip for instance), then the driver is unable to start in the first stage (`java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question! First of all, as you know Apache Zeppelin runs [interpreters in a separate processes](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/development/writingzeppelininterpreter.html#what-is-apache-zeppelin-interpreter).

[image: Apache Zeppelin architecture diagram]

In your case, Spark interpreter JVM process hosts a `SparkContext` and serves as a`SparkDriver` instance for the `yarn-client` deployment mode. This process inside the container, according to the [Apache Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html), needs to be able to communicate *back and forth* to\from YARN ApplicationMaster and all SparkWorkers machines of the cluster.

[image: Apache Spark architecture diagram]

This implies that you have to have [number of ports](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking) open and manually forwarded between the container and a host machine. Here is [an example of a project at ZEPL](https://github.com/ZEPL/z-manager/blob/master/multitenancy/server/docker.go#L64) doing similar job, where it took us **7 ports** to get the job done.

Anoter aproach can be running Docker networking in a [host mode](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/what-is-docker-networking#Host-Mode-Networking) (though it apparently does not work on os x, due to [a recent bug](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/68))